# What is the right way to deal with the PreparedStatement in the Java program flow?

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, prepared-statement

There are two methods in which the PreparedStatement is used.

The first method is called in the second method.

**First method:**

```
protected List<String> findResultsByMandantId(Long mandantId) {
    List<String> resultIds = new ArrayList<>();
    ResultSet rs;
    String sql = "SELECT result_id FROM results WHERE mandant_id = ?";
    PreparedStatement statement = getPreparedStatement(sql, false);
    try {
        statement.setLong(1, mandantId);
        statement.execute();
        rs = statement.getResultSet();

        while (rs.next()) {
            resultIds.add(rs.getString(1));
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
    return resultIds;
}
```

**Second method:**

```
protected void findResultLineEntityToDelete(Long mandantId, String title, String context) {
    List<String> resultIds = findResultsByMandantId(mandantId);
    String [] resultIdsArr = resultIds.toArray(String[]::new);
    
    ResultSet rs;

    //String sql = "SELECT * FROM resultline WHERE result_id in (SELECT result_id FROM results WHERE mandant_id =" + mandantId + ")";
    String sql = "SELECT * FROM resultline WHERE result_id in (" + String.join(", ", resultIdsArr)+ ")";
    PreparedStatement statement = getPreparedStatement(sql, false);
    try {
        statement.execute();
        rs = statement.getResultSet();

        while (rs.next()) {
            if (rs.getString(3).equals(title) && rs.getString(4).equals(context)) {
                System.out.println("Titel: " + rs.getString(3) + " " + "Context: " + rs.getString(4));
            }
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

The class in which both methods are located extends the JDBCBaseManager.

**JDBCBaseManager:**

```
private final String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/database";
private final String userName = "root";
private final String password = "";
private Connection connection = null;
private PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;
private int batchSize = 0;


public JDBCBaseManager() {
//      Dotenv env = Dotenv.configure().directory("./serverless").load();
//      url = env.get("DB_PROD_URL");
//      userName = env.get("DB_USER");
//      password = env.get("DB_PW");
}

public void getConnection() {
    try {
        if (connection == null) {
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, userName, password);
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}

public PreparedStatement getPreparedStatement(String sql, boolean returnGeneratedKeys) {
    try {
        if (connection == null) {
            getConnection();
        }
        if (preparedStatement == null) {
            if (!returnGeneratedKeys) {
                preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
            } else {
                preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(sql, Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
                connection.setAutoCommit(false);
            }
        }
        return preparedStatement;
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}

public void closeConnection() {
    try {
        if (connection != null && !connection.isClosed()) {
            System.out.println("Closing Database Connection");
            connection.close();
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}

public void startBatch(int batchSize) throws SQLException {
    connection.setAutoCommit(false);
    setBatchSize(batchSize);
}

public void commit() {
    try {
        if (connection != null && !connection.isClosed()) {
            connection.commit();
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}

public int getBatchSize() {
    return batchSize;
}

public void setBatchSize(int batchSize) {
    this.batchSize = batchSize;
}
```

The ResultSet in the second method still contains the results from the first method.

I already tried to close the connection and open it again before the second method is executed, but then I get the errors:

> java.sql.SQLException: No operations allowed after statement closed.
>
> java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: No operations allowed
> after connection closed.

Can you tell me how to deal with the statement correctly in this case? Is my BaseManager incorrectly structured?

Comment: Never, ever concatenate strings. Use PreparedStatement with parameters. Your code is open to SQL Injection.

Comment: Correct this still needs to be changed... is not yet a productionCode... at the moment I am concerned with the statement problem

Comment: After you close the connection in method1. When you get a new connection, you call getConnection(), but if it is null it create new connection. I m assuming it is not null but it is still the closed first connection. Maybe an if statement to check `.isClosed()` and create new connection? I m too sure, but I really dont see you creating new connection anywhere.

Comment: Unfortunately it does not work, I get the same error message as mentioned above.

Comment: after `connection.close();` in closeConnection() can you try reassigning `connection = null;`?

Comment: yerah i did this... same result.. I also tried to close the statement - java.sql.SQLException: No operations allowed after statement closed.

Comment: Your `JDBCBaseManager` makes zero sense to me. You are wrapping resources incorrectly. Use a `DataSource` to create connections and use the JDBC interfaces **directly**, or switch to using abstractions like Hibernate/JPA or jOOQ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here lies the error

```
public JDBCBaseManager() {

  private PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;

    public PreparedStatement getPreparedStatement(String sql, boolean returnGeneratedKeys) {
      try {
      ......
       if (preparedStatement == null) {
            if (!returnGeneratedKeys) {
                preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
            } else {
                preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(sql, Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
                connection.setAutoCommit(false);
            }
        }
        return preparedStatement;
```

You build the prepare statement only the first time the method `getPreparedStatement` is called because only the first time the field `preparedStatement` is null. Every next time you call the method `getPreparedStatement`  you receive the previous  `preparedStatement`  from the previous SQL and not the new one.

Remove the check for `if (preparedStatement == null) {`

You need to build a new `preparedStatement` every time you want to execute a new SQL.